# File Upload speed factors

Tags: upload

I am working of file Upload features.I would like to know more about File Upload. File Upload speed depends on which factors ? Thanks

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: They're mainly limited by `c`, the speed of light. Another approach would be that each component that takes part in an upload has a possible impact. Most of them are probably not operating even near `c`. So most uploads will tend to be way slower.

Comment: Fellow moderators, why is this problem considered too broad?

Comment: @WongJiaHau Sites in the Stack Exchange network are (arguably) geared towards solvable, "medium length" problems. This question 1) doesn't really ask a concrete, (potentially) solvable question (e.g. "why are are my file uploads slow?") and 2) requests information that people have literally written books about in terms of volume (not long-form internet articles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File upload speeds generally depend on two factors:

- Network upload speed (ability to transfer data).
- Application speed (ability to process data).

**Network upload speed** can be limited by:

*Physical Transmission Medium*

This includes wired vs. wireless connections and copper vs. fiber optic cables between all points along the data path.

Typically, wired connections conduct signals better than air and thus are faster than wireless. Between fiber optic cable and traditional copper-based cables, fiber transmits data using light rather than electricity and thus is faster. Cables may also be manufactured to certain specifications which can affect their speed of data transmission.

*Transmission Hardware*

Transmission hardware speed can limit the rate at which data can be processed (excluding transmission mediums).

This applies to the devices used to pass along data such as network interface cards, modems, routers, hubs, switches, hardware firewalls, etc.

These types of hardware limits apply to routing on local networks as well as connecting larger separate networks together.

Failed hardware which has to be routed around or may otherwise be slow to respond can also have a negative impact on data speeds.

*Interference*

Interference includes:

- spurious noise on the medium (particularly wireless transmissions where other devices may inadvertently transmit electromagnetic signals that aren't data).
- physical barriers (again, particularly for wireless, although overcoming physical barriers may increase transmission distance - - which may have a negative impact overall).
- packet collisions (two devices transmitting on the same medium at the same time).

*Physical Distance*

Physical distance between sending and receiving locations tends to degrade signals as they lose power eventually or it otherwise takes a non-trivial amount of time for them to travel from one location to another.

*Active Bandwidth Limits*

Active bandwidth limits can be applied at any point along the transmission path. For example, these limits are often imposed by a service provider to ease network congestion or divide services into artificial product tiers.

**Receiving application speed** can limit upload speeds as well. This speed is affected by all the items referenced above under network upload speeds, as well as:

*Application Speed*

The execution speed of the application receiving the data has an impact on how fast data is uploaded.

*Active Limits*

Active limits set by the party running the receiver (similar to, but independent of, general bandwidth restrictions on a network) can affect speed. This may be motivated by as simple a goal as to not overwhelm the server.

*Incidental Limits*

Things such as programming language, software libraries and transmission protocol limits (such as http vs. https and error correction handling) can all have an impact on the speed at which data is handled.

*Server Speed*

This is regulated by the physical hardware of the server, which includes items such as:

- hard disk speeds (including things such as magnetic disks vs. SSDs, connection type, and single disks vs. e.g RAID arrays).
- processor speeds or quantity.
- miscellaneous components such as chipset, internal cables and bus speeds.
- memory speed/quantity.